# Socket.io returns "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined" error in hottowel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I've been using john papa's hottowel for a while now and tackling on how to use the [socket-io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) but getting nowhere. I already read some articles and answers in Stack Overflow, but can't seem to find the answer. The socket doesn't seem to work and I don't know the problem. I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined at dashboard:208

Here's my code:

**app.js**

```js
/*jshint node:true*/
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); // it was require('socket.io')(server);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8001;
var four0four = require('./utils/404')();
var multer = require('multer');

var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/favicon.ico'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: '50mb',
  extended: true,
  parameterLimit: 50000
}));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes'));

mongoose.connect(
  'mongodb://localhost/hrisdb',
  { useMongoClient: true },
  function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Not connected to Remote Database' + err);
    } else {
      console.log('Successfully connected Remote Database');
    }
  });

console.log('connection', mongoose.connection.readyState);

console.log('About to crank up node');
console.log('PORT=' + port);
console.log('NODE_ENV=' + environment);

switch (environment) {
  case 'build':
    console.log('** BUILD **');
    app.use(express.static('./build/'));
    // Any invalid calls for templateUrls are under app/* and should return 404
    app.use('/app/*', function (req, res, next) {
      four0four.send404(req, res);
    });
    // Any deep link calls should return index.html
    app.use('/*', express.static('./build/index.html'));
    break;
  default:
    console.log('** DEV **');
    app.use(express.static('./src/client/'));
    app.use(express.static('./'));
    app.use(express.static('./tmp'));
    // Any invalid calls for templateUrls are under app/* and should return 404
    app.use('/app/*', function (req, res, next) {
      four0four.send404(req, res);
    });
    // Any deep link calls should return index.html
    app.use('/*', express.static('./src/client/index.html'));
    break;
}

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
  console.log('env = ' + app.get('env') +
    '\n__dirname = ' + __dirname +
    '\nprocess.cwd = ' + process.cwd());
});
```

**client side code**

```html
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      console.log('a user connected');
      socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnected');
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: I can't see any mention of `dashboard` in your code, but it's mentioned in the error. Do you have any more details of where that error is coming from?

Comment: As in, please say _where_ you saw this error (browser console? cli?) and provide the full error stack, otherwise it's very difficult to deduce where it's coming from

Comment: @MattFletcher im getting the error in my **browser console**